# Is it possible to Chef `include_recipe` and indicate `only_if`/not_if` condition?

Tags: chef-infra

I want to `include_recipe` `only_if` some condition is met. The following code doesn't raise any error but it doesn't care about the `only_if` condition either, so gets executed in any cases:

```
include_recipe "cubrid" do
    only_if "hostname | grep 'blahblahshouldnotmatch'"
end
```

**Is it possible to `include_recipe` only on some condition?**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`include_recipe` isn't a normal resources in Chef but a normal method. Because of that, it ignores the passed block and subsequently the `only_if` condition specified there.

Fortunately, there occurs to be a solution for this. **flaccid** user from #chef freenode channel suggested the following solution, which works perfectly.

```ruby
this_node_is_shard_broker = node["hostname"].include? "node2"
include_recipe "cubrid" if this_node_is_shard_broker
```

The above will execute `include_recipe` only if the hostname of the current running node is `node2`, which is exactly what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: `include_recipe` seems to be just a normal ruby function call and therefore you can use plain ruby `if <condition> <code> end`.

Answer (score 9):

This works just fine:

```
include_recipe "foo" if node['bar'] == 'baz'
```

Answer (score 4):

The above didn't work for me, but the following did:

```
if node["hostname"].include? "node2"
  include_recipe "cubrid"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In all answers that suggest

```
include_recipe "foo" if node['bar'] == 'baz'
```

you forget one extremely important thing - this if is evaluated in compile phase and if node['bar'] is changed during the course of execution this if will deliver the wrong result, as it is will be based on original, and not on changed value.

One can argue, that this is a bad practice, but think twice before doing that. Just an example:
installing packages in chef-client run is a common practice. Reload ohai plugin packages after that can be seen as a good practice, but what will happen with the code:

```
include_recipe "my_cookbook::install" unless node['packages'].key?('mypackage')
```

in case when mypackage is installed somewhere in a cookbook that is executed earlier in the same client run? The right answer is that recipe will be included, while it is clear from the code, that expectation is that it is not.

Unfortunately I at least does not know the way how to solve this issue, as both include_recipe and possible condition are compiled phase evaluated. AFAIK there is no way for conditional including of the recipe based on actions taken by other cookbooks withing the same chef-client run.

Comment: I think if you really want to make a recipe conditional on an attribute which may change during a Chef run, your only option is to make every resource within the recipe conditional. But that's a pretty rare use case. More commonly one would like to pass a string to `only_if` which would be interpreted by a custom interpreter, and now would have to manually do the work of calling that interpreter and distilling a boolean from its output. Inconvenient, but generally acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching for a dynamic way to accomplish including a recipe by condition. Having the `only_if` keyword available natively in Chef would have been perfect.

The existing mechanisms like `include_recipe cookbook::recipe if [condition]` seem to be static and won't work if the condition changes in the middle of the converge.

With that in mind, I figured out you can include a recipe from a resource. I built a custom resource simply for including a recipe. Then I can apply a guard to the new resource.

```
resource_name :conditional_include

property :recipe, String, name_property: true

default_action :apply

action :apply do
    include_recipe new_resource.recipe
end
```

Then I can use this resource to include a recipe dynamically while also allowing a guard to be defined.

```
conditional_include 'cookbook::recipe' do
    only_if { [condition] }
end
```

Since `only_if` is a construct provided by Chef, you can use any of the `only_if` or `not_if` constructs to create your condition.

NOTE: After coming up with this approach, I've found other unrelated posts that also include a recipe from a resource using a dynamic recipe name. So this approach has been around for a while, just not necessarily for this specific purpose.